# How to add Extra Parameters in AWS SNS Publish method via server using c#.net

Tags: c#, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want to send extra parameters from the server using AWS SNS publish method. But this class has only few properties. But i also want to add custom properties like userId, statusId etc. that consists of my apps data. These properties should be out of the "aps" dictionary. Below is the format of the payload am trying to send from server.

```
{
GroupId = 0;
GroupName = "";
IsGroup = 0;
PostId = 0;
ReceiverId = 8;
SenderId = 3;
Status = 3;
aps = {
alert = "Kalyan sent you a message";
badge = 1;
sound = default;
};
}
```

Can some one guide me how to construct the following format of pay load using c#.net with publish method or any other alternative.

Thanks in advance,

Regards
Kalyan

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post and it's looking for a C# solution however using the AWS SNS V2 library, here is some sample code for this in Ruby which you should be able to port:

https://gist.github.com/jkotchoff/0b2bf23b28874596ac90#file-aws_sns_push_notification-rb-L100

The important part for you is probably construction of a GCM compatible JSON structure like:

```
GCM: {
  data: {
    message: "Hello World from Ruby AWS",
    notification_id: "15",
    collapse_key: "Ruby AWS",
    time_to_live: time_to_live_seconds
  }
}.to_json
```

whereby **notification_id** is a custom property